# Delete temporary views after 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

I have a table `temp_views` which should stores views based on the user's IP. If the view is 1 hour old, I want to delete it from the table.

```
// Update views

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_views WHERE v_postid=? AND v_ip=?");
$stmt->bind_param("is",$pid,$ip);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($temp_view);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if ($temp_view == 0){

  // Insert a temporary view for 1 hr

  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO temp_views (v_ip,v_postid) VALUES (?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("si",$ip,$pid);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

  // Add view to post

  $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET p_views=p_views+1 WHERE p_id=?");
  $stmt->bind_param("i",$pid);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: add a timestamp-column which holds the time when the view shall be deleted. write a cronjob that runs every minute or so and deletes the views whichs timestamps are in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a new timestamp field `createdTime` in your table `temp_views`. So that you can set a cron job that will do a delete query which deletes the one hour old records.

In case of TIMESTAMP, Use

```
 DELETE FROM `temp_views` WHERE createdTime < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600);
```

If it is DATETIME field, use the below one

```
 DELETE FROM `temp_views` WHERE `createdTime` < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1HOUR);
```

Comment: If `createdTime` is a timestamp like `1455012086`, how would the SQL look? That's giving me an error

Comment: @frosty In case of time-stamp you have to use another query. I updated my answer please check.